# How to play the mp3 file in AudioTrack in android, ? by taking input from resource folder

Tags: android

How to play audio file in Android? Basically I am trying to play audio from Android by getting the input from a resource folder. Is this code snippet correct?

```
int minSize =AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize( 22050, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );
        track = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 22050,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                minSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    try {
        audioFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void audioFile() throws IOException{
    InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.e_sanje);

    byte[] voice = null;
    voice = new byte[input.available()];
    voice = convertToByte(input);
    input.close();

    track.play();
    track.write(voice, 0 ,voice.length);
    track.stop();

}

public static byte[] convertToByte(InputStream is) throws IOException{

    ByteArrayOutputStream baOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[10240];
    int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length))>0){
        baOutput.write(buff, 0, i);
    }
    return baOutput.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add some comment what you're stuck with. As it is now, it's hard to tell what you're exactly asking about

Comment: Thanks,  I want change the voice of the audio file, like male voice to female and vice versa. with out changing the length of the file.  can you help me....

Comment: how to change the frequency of male voice to female voice and vice versa, kindly help me....